# php openssl PKI Encrypt & Decrypt

Tags: php, linux, encryption, cryptography

I encrypt my file with

```
openssl_public_encrypt($input,$encrypted,$publickey,OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

When I want decrypt in Linux with openssl get some errors:

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:rsa_pk1.c:190:
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:674:
```

Linux command:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey PrivateKeyAES256.pem
```

Comment: Have you tried using the PHP function openssl_public_decrypt() to decrypt the data after you have encrypted it? Also, do you save the encrypted data to the file using Base64 encoding?

Comment: I tried decrypt with openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem,there is no problem with php side

Comment: See the question posted here for some suggestions: [Can't decrypt RSA data with open SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228128/cant-decrypt-rsa-data-with-open-ssl) It is possible that the PEM file needs to be converted, or perhaps was not generated correctly. Another possibility (which I mentioned in my comment) is that the data is Base64-encoded in your script but this option has not been specified at the command line.